Reference on $ A^{\times} = N_{L/K}(B^{\times})$ iff $L/K$ is unramified.
Let $L/K$ be a finite separable extension of local fields. I know how to show if $L/K$ is unramified, then $ A^{\times} = N_{L/K}(B^{\times})$. The converse direction seems much harder.
Let $k,l$ be the residue fields of $K,L$ respectively. I considered the special case where $L/K$ is totally tamely ramified. In this case, $l=k$, and if $\pi_A$ is a uniformizer, then $B = A[\pi_A^{1/n}]$ where $n = [L\colon K]$. It's not difficult to show $N_{L/K}(a) \equiv a^n (\bmod\; \mathfrak{m}_K)$ for all $a\in A$ because the map $N_{L/K}$ reduces to $N_{k/k}^n, x \mapsto x^n$. This map is surjective iff $\gcd(n, \#k - 1) = 1$. If this map is not surjective then we do have $ A^{\times} \supsetneq N_{L/K}(B^{\times})$, but when it is surjective I'm not sure what I can do.

The converse is much harder because it is false. Let $K = \mathbf{Q}_2$ and $L = \mathbf{Q}2(2^{1/3})$, and $A = \mathbf{Z}2$. Certainly $B$ contains $A$ and so $N{L/K}(B^{\times})$ contains $N{L/K}(A^{\times}) = A^{\times 3}$.
But $A^{\times}/A^{\times 3} = 1$ so the norm map is surjective on units even though $L/K$ is certainly ramified. The result is true if $L/K$ is abelian as follows from local class field theory.
